# text button in flutter doesn't work. not responding to clicks

Tags: flutter

I'm beginner flutter. and i add textButton to my application. But it didn't working. not responding to clicks. it not getting any output. i trying many ways i didnt get any output. please some one can teach me what's wrong??

```
TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    return Alert(
                      context: context,
                      type: AlertType.warning,
                      title: "RFLUTTER ALERT",
                      desc: "Flutter is more awesome with RFlutter Alert.",
                      buttons: [
                        DialogButton(
                          child: Text(
                            "FLAT",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 179, 134, 1.0),
                        ),
                        DialogButton(
                          child: Text(
                            "GRADIENT",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                          gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                            Color.fromRGBO(116, 116, 191, 1.0),
                            Color.fromRGBO(52, 138, 199, 1.0)
                          ]),
                        )
                      ],
                    ).show();
                  },
                  child: Text("X", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white,),)
                ),
```

but this is inside of Align>Row>children [my code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nlfje.png)

also i added dependency to pubspec.yml to get this alert message.
also this code is its example.

I JUST NEED TO WORK THIS ONPRESSD OF TEXTBOTTON.

Answer (score 0):

follow this code and try to implement it:

```
showTestDialog(BuildContext context){
showDialog(context: context, builder: (context)=>AlertDialog(
  title: Text("Test"),
  actions: <Widget>[
    //implement Your Code
   ],
 ));
}
```

And then call this in onPressed by calling the above method. I hope that solves your problem.

Happy Coding